# Flutter how to set the step number?

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5PnM.png)

Hi, how do I set the step number? Example step 1 will show the Past medical history radio button. After selecting Yes or No, click the Next button to enter past surgical history questions and a radio button will be shown. I have set the step number but the question does not appear. Just show the button.

My code:

```
override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(children: [
          _isLoading
              ? const LinearProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: DefaultTheme.accentColor,
                  valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(DefaultTheme.primaryColor),
                  minHeight: 3,
                )
              : Container(),
          Container(
            height: 52.0,
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                bottom: BorderSide(
                  color: DefaultTheme.borderColor,
                  width: 1,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: const TopBar(pageTitle: "Verification Form"),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width > 800
                ? 700
                : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                _stepno > 1
                    ? _stepno != 2
                        ? Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, top: 20),
                            child: LinearPercentIndicator(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
                              lineHeight: 20.0,
                              animationDuration: 3000,
                              percent: _completionPercentage,
                              animateFromLastPercent: true,
                              center: Text(
                                "$_stepno/2",
                                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              barRadius: const Radius.circular(5),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                              progressColor: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          )
                        : const SizedBox(height: 0)
                    : const SizedBox(height: 0),
                _stepno == 1
                    ? Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const Text(
                            "Past medical history: ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                height: 1.5),
                          ),
                          RadioListTile(
                            title: const Text("Yes"),
                            value: "yes",
                            groupValue: _medicalhistory,
                            //onChanged: handleSelection
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                _medicalhistory = value!;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          if (_medicalhistory == "yes") ...[
                            const Text(
                                "If yes, please share and describe the previous medical illness: "),
                            const SizedBox(height: 5),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 60,
                              child: TextField(
                                controller: _medicalillness,
                                maxLength: 1000,
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                ),
                                maxLines: 1,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: [
                                TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    _medicalhistory = _medicalillness.text;
                                  },
                                  child: const Text("Save"),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                          RadioListTile(
                            title: const Text("No"),
                            value: "no",
                            groupValue: _medicalhistory,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                _medicalhistory = value.toString();
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    : const SizedBox(height: 0),
                _stepno == 2
                    ? Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          const Text(
                            "Past surgical history: ",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 14,
                                height: 1.5),
                          ),
                          RadioListTile(
                            title: const Text("Yes"),
                            value: "yes",
                            groupValue: _surgicalhistory,
                            //onChanged: handleSelection
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                _surgicalhistory = value!;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          if (_surgicalhistory == "yes") ...[
                            const Text(
                                "If yes, please share and describe the previous surgical illness: "),
                            const SizedBox(height: 5),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 60,
                              child: TextField(
                                controller: _surgicalillness,
                                maxLength: 1000,
                                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                ),
                                maxLines: 1,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: [
                                TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    _surgicalhistory = _surgicalillness.text;
                                  },
                                  child: const Text("Save"),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                          RadioListTile(
                            title: const Text("No"),
                            value: "no",
                            groupValue: _surgicalhistory,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                _surgicalhistory = value.toString();
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    : const SizedBox(height: 0),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: _stepno > 1
                    ? Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                        height: 45,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: AppConst.primaryColor,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(5.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Center(
                          child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              _previous();
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              "Previous",
                              maxLines: 1,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    : const SizedBox(height: 1),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                  height: 45,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: AppConst.primaryColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(5.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        if (_stepno < 2) {
                          _validateFormfieldAndMoveToNext();
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        "Next",
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }

  _previous() {
    if (_stepno > 1) {
      if (_stepno == 2) {
        //_stepno = 7; // skip gendius
        setState(() {
          _completionPercentage = (_stepno / 100) * 10;
        });
      } else {
        _stepno--;
        setState(() {
          _completionPercentage = (_stepno / 100) * 10;
        });
      }
    }
  }

  _validateFormfieldAndMoveToNext() async {
    if (_stepno >= 2) {
      if (_medicalhistory == "No") {
        /*createToast(
            _fToast, false, txt["please_answer_the_displayed_question"]);*/
        return;
      }
    }
    if (_stepno >= 2) {
      if (_surgicalhistory == "No") {
        /*createToast(
            _fToast, false, txt["please_answer_the_displayed_question"]);*/
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l3ix.png)

When I remove the step number in the code for the medical history and surgical history questions, the questions will appear but are on one page. I plan that when in step one, only the medical history question will appear. After you have finished answering and click the next button, only the surgical history question will appear. Can anyone help me how to make it like that?

Answer (score 0):

*This is more of a comment than an answer, as you'll have to tweak your current code.*

> ...I plan that when in step one, only the medical history question will appear. After you have finished answering and click the next button, only the surgical history question will appear.

There's actually a built-in widget for this. It's called [`Stepper`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html) and I'd recommend that you use it instead.

[image]
Take from the docs:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Flutter code sample for [Stepper].

void main() => runApp(const StepperExampleApp());

class StepperExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const StepperExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Stepper Sample')),
        body: const Center(
          child: StepperExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class StepperExample extends StatefulWidget {
  const StepperExample({super.key});

  @override
  State<StepperExample> createState() => _StepperExampleState();
}

class _StepperExampleState extends State<StepperExample> {
  int _index = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stepper(
      currentStep: _index,
      onStepCancel: () {
        if (_index > 0) {
          setState(() {
            _index -= 1;
          });
        }
      },
      onStepContinue: () {
        if (_index <= 0) {
          setState(() {
            _index += 1;
          });
        }
      },
      onStepTapped: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          _index = index;
        });
      },
      steps: <Step>[
        Step(
          title: const Text('Step 1 title'),
          content: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: const Text('Content for Step 1'),
          ),
        ),
        const Step(
          title: Text('Step 2 title'),
          content: Text('Content for Step 2'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Based on my code, how do I modify it? My design is based on a wireframe.

Comment: @John well, this answer was just an example. I dont' currently have the time to modify your code, but you can take a look at the official docs linked in this answer. or wait for someone else to reply..

Comment: It's ok i try to modify. I hope it's working. Thanks for you help.